# "Make" sub-directory preferred method

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

What is the standard ? And in which case we should use the following ?

```
$(MAKE) -C subdir

cd subdir && $(MAKE)

cd subdir ; $(MAKE)
```

same for when doing make clean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a diagram:

```
Method  | Correct | Cross-platform
--------+---------+---------------
-C      |    X    |     
&&      |    X    |      X
 ;      |         |      X
```

`-C` works well for GNU make, but [is not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html).

`;` works equally poorly on all platforms (if `subdir` is inaccessible, it results in an infinite loop).

`&&` is both correct and portable, and therefore the best option.

Comment: awesome ! any reference to those or it's from personal experience ?

Comment: I added a source for POSIX. The result of using `;` vs `&&` are just side effects of how they work (`;` executes commands sequentially regardless of exit code, `&&` executes sequentially but only if the previous command succeeds).